# simple insert in postgres taking too long

Tags: postgresql

I checked pg_stat_activity.query_start to list down queries taking more than 2 mins and found one of the simple inserts in the output. The table just has 4 records in there, so I can't imagine indexing slowing it down.

I am unable to figure out the reason of the same. Can someone please suggest.

```
INSERT INTO events(event_id, alert_type, payload, received_at) VALUES('21', 'IMMEDIATE', '{"title":"IMMEDIATE ALERT - Far Western","message":"test immediate message.","url":"https://www.test-example.com"}', 1553356287962) RETURNING id;


\d events;
                                         Table "public.events"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                Default                
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 event_id | text                        |           | not null | 
 alert_type  | alert_type                  |           |          | 
 payload     | json                        |           |          | 
 received_at | bigint                      |           | not null | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |           |          | now()
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "events_event_id_received_at_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (event_id, received_at)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "event_polygons" CONSTRAINT "events_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "notifications" CONSTRAINT "events_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    create_notifications AFTER INSERT ON events DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_notifications()
```

The insert happens in a transaction and it has associated multiPolygons which get inserted in child table event_polygons

```
devTestSetup=> SELECT                             
  pid,
  now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS duration,
  query,
  state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '1 minute';
  pid  |    duration     |                                                                                                                                                   query                                                                                                                                                    | state  
-------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 14877 | 00:04:09.142522 | commit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | active
 18019 | 00:01:07.521619 | INSERT INTO events(event_id, alert_type, payload, received_at) VALUES('1', 'IMMEDIATE', '{"title":"IMMEDIATE ALERT -  Far North Coast","message":"test immediate message.","url":"https://www.test-example.com"}', 1553356287742) RETURNING id | active

 17172 | 00:02:08.377769 | INSERT INTO events(event_id, alert_type, payload, received_at) VALUES('1', 'IMMEDIATE', '{"title":"IMMEDIATE ALERT -  Far North Coast","message":"test immediate message.","url":"https://www.test-example.com"}', 1553356287742) RETURNING id | active
 16070 | 00:03:08.764471 | commit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | idle
 16071 | 00:03:07.424489 | commit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | idle
 16072 | 00:03:08.764385 | commit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | idle
 16074 | 00:03:08.764946 | commit
```

Comment: Can trigger on the table a cause for it, because the procedure create_notifications takes long like 3-4 mins? But I do not see the select in stored procedure in pg_stat_activity.

Comment: Run your insert with `explain (analyze)` and you will see where the time is spent

Comment: Here is the output of explain analyze  - ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "events_event_id_received_at_key"
DETAIL:  Key (event_id, received_at)=(14, 1553415139492) already exists. It took quite a bit almost 3mins for the response to show up. Can it be that the same query is execute multiple times(almost 8) in parallel and therefore the issue?

Comment: I dropped the trigger on the table and all the inserts worked in one go. Is it that the trigger is happening before the commit of INSERT INTO event and INSERT INTO event_polygons transaction ?

Comment: If select of stored procedure is stuck, why don't I see it in output of pg_stat_activity?